# How to change behavior enter/backspace pressed in WYMEDITOR

Tags: javascript, key, wymeditor

In Google Chrome after pressing enter key in WYMEDITOR a new `<p>` is created. How to change it? I would rather insert `<br />` tag as it happens after shift-enter combination. (In fact shift-enter creates two `<br />`).

Similar question concerns backspace pressed on the beginning of paragraph. How to change this behavior to erase paragraph (or other) only when it is empty and do nothing otherwise.

I'll be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Considering WYMEditor takes a markup approach I'm pretty sure they intended not having an option for adding `<br />` tags.

I reckon you could write a plugin for the behavior you're looking for..